# Maven Dependency Plugin option excludeScope doesn't work for build-classpath command

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm trying to build classpath with skipping dependencies with test scope. I tried this command

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=path.txt -Dmdep.excludeScope=test
```

But I still have all jars for all scopes in path.txt. Can somebody tell me if I do something wrong?

Comment: For what purpose do you need that?

Comment: BTW: What does `mvn dependency:tree` showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-DexcludeScope=test` to follow the [plugin documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html#excludeScope):

`mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=path.txt -DexcludeScope=test`

but expect it to fail, according to this [Maven's issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MDEP-85).

To include all dependences besides ones with `test` scope, consider using `-DincludeScope=compile`